# Node js check if a file is already open or not

Tags: node.js, fs

I need to check if a file is opened or not before doing some process like copy in node js. How can I check the status of a file to see if it is opened or not?

Comment: You're writing like entering phrases in Google. Take more than 10 seconds if you expect an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fs.open function with r+ parameter.

> 'r+' - Open file for reading and writing. An exception occurs if the file does not exist.